# I want all the UI copy in my iOS app contained in a single, easy-to-audit file. What are good approaches?

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have a large product which bursts with UI copy. There's a lot of important context and instruction the app offers and ongoing accuracy is important.

So that means tons of editing and auditing, to make sure things are clear, accurate and up-to-date.

In service of this, I'd like all the copy contained in a single file that's easy for non-technical folks to review and edit.

The product is US-only and will be for the foreseeable future, so localization isn't a prime concern.

I know that NSLocalizedString can provide a strings file with english content that can be overridden.

I could also use a Plist file and define key names for each piece of copy.

Is one of these approaches better than the other? Is there another I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Use NSLocalizedString, it does everything you want with the benefit of preparing your app for localization if you ever decide to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the way to do it is NSLocalizedString and a .strings file with all the copy in it, then it's in the right place for localization in the future.

Localizing strings in your xib files is a little bit more cumbersome. Apple used to recommend duplicating xib files for each localization, which was ridiculous. I use a routine I wrote that localizes loaded xib files when they are loaded, by traversing down the view heirarchy and replacing the strings loaded from the xib with the whatever NSLocalizedString returns. It works well. I don't know if things have improved with apple with this as I haven't checked up on this for a while

Answer (score 0):

You can load strings from several separate `.strings` files, which can be automatically generated from different parts of the project and the storyboard. It's not necessary to turn  on localization.

Take a look at [String Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/loadingresources/Strings/Strings.html)